# Rails - nested loops inside view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, nested

I'm taking up rails as a hobby but I'm still fairly new so apologies if this sounds ridiculous. I'm creating a board that can have many statuses. And each status can have many notes. However, this error comes up once I added the notes loop into the status loop on the view:

```
undefined method `notes' for nil:NilClass
```

Snippet of the boards/show.html.erb file:

```
<% @board.statuses.each do |status| %>
    <div>
        <h2><%= link_to status.name, status_url(status)%></h2>
        <% @status.notes.each do |note| %>
            <h2><%= link_to notes.content, note_url(note)%></h2>
        <% end %>
        <%= link_to 'New notes', new_note_path(@note)  %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong within the controllers or the view though. I've been having a hard time figuring it out. I appreciate any help though!

**notes_controller**:

```
class NotesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @note = Note.new
  end
  def create
    Note.create(note_params.merge(status_id: current_user.id))
    redirect_to boards_url
  end
  def delete
    Note.find(params[:id]).destroy(note_params)
  end
  def update
    Note.find(params[:id]).update(note_params)
  end
  def note_params
    params.require(:note).permit(:status_id, :content)
  end
end
```

**statuses_controller**:

```
class StatusesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @status = Status.new
  end
  def create
    Status.create(status_params.merge(board_id: current_user.id))
    redirect_to :root
  end
  def delete
    Status.find(params[:id]).destroy(status_params)
  end
  def update
    Status.find(params[:id]).update(status_params)
  end
  def show
    @status = Status.find(params[:id])
  end
  def status_params
    params.require(:status).permit(:board_id, :name)
  end
end
```

Any more information required then let me know. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking it should look more like:

```
<% @board.statuses.each do |status| %>
  <div>
    <h2><%= link_to status.name, status_url(status)%></h2>
    <% status.notes.each do |note| %>
      <h2><%= link_to notes.content, note_url(note)%></h2>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to 'New notes', new_note_path(@note)  %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

So that you're using the `notes` from the `status` in a given loop.

Comment: I used this code before but it still resulted in an error.

Comment: Actually no wait, it works now. Thank you! No more errors.

Comment: Great! Please feel free to upvote and/or accept (helpful to me and to future SO searchers).

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because in this line `<% @status.notes.each do |note| %>` the view is expecting to be passed `@status` object from the `show` action in the board's controller. Since you aren't passing that `@status`, it's `nil` and `nil` doesn't have the method `notes`.

As @jvillian pointed out, it should be `<% status.notes.each do |note| %>` because you want to get the notes from the statuses you're iterating over with `each` in this line: `<% @board.statuses.each do |status| %>`